# initialize all variables but still get NullPointerExceptions error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Here is the code:

```
public class Fisher{

    private String name;
    private Fish [] fishCaught;
    private int numFishCaught;
    private int keepSize;
    public static int LIMIT =10;
    private boolean full;

    public int getnumFishCaught(){
        return numFishCaught;
    }
    public Fisher(String n,int k){
        this.name=n;
        this.keepSize=k;
        this.fishCaught =new Fish[LIMIT];

    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.name + " with " + numFishCaught+ " fish ";
    }
    public void keep(Fish f){
        if(numFishCaught<LIMIT){
            this.fishCaught[numFishCaught]=f;
            numFishCaught++;
            full=false;
        }else{
            full=true;
            numFishCaught=LIMIT;
        }

    }
    public boolean likes(Fish f1){
        if(f1.getSpecies().equals("Sunfish")){
            return false;
        }else{
            if(f1.getSize()>=this.keepSize){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public void listFish(){

        System.out.println( this.name +" with "+ numFishCaught + " fish as follow:　");
        for(int i=0;i<numFishCaught;i++){
            System.out.println("A " + this.fishCaught[i].getSize() +" cm " + this.fishCaught[i].getSpecies());
        }
    }
    public void goFishingIn(Pond p){

        if(likes(p.catchAFish())){ // the problem happens here
            keep(p.catchAFish());
            if(full==true)
                p.add(p.catchAFish());
        }
    }
    public void giveAwayFish(Fisher f1,Pond pp){
        this.keepSize=f1.keepSize;
        for(int i=0;i<numFishCaught;i++){
            if(likes(fishCaught[i])==true){
                f1.keep(fishCaught[i]);
            }else{
                pp.add(fishCaught[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the other two classes, Fish and Pond, which are:

```
public class Pond {

    private Fish [] fish;
    private int numFish;
    private int capacity;
    private boolean full;
    private Fish fff;

    public Pond(int c){

        capacity=c;
        fish= new Fish[capacity];
        fff= new Fish(0,"UNKNOWN");
    }
    public boolean isFull(){

        if(numFish>capacity){
            full=true;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            full=false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int getNumFish(){
        return numFish;
    }

    public void add(Fish f){

        if(full==false){
            fish[numFish]=f;
            numFish++;
        } 
    } 
    public void listFish(){

        System.out.println("Pond with " + numFish + " fish as follow:　");
        for(int i=0;i<numFish;i++){
            System.out.println("A " + fish[i].getSize() +" cm " + fish[i].getSpecies());
        }
    }
    public Fish catchAFish(){

        int num= (int)(Math.random() * (numFish-1));
        if(fish[num]!=null && numFish>0){
            fff= fish[num];
            fish[num]= fish[numFish-1];
            fish[numFish-1]=null;
            numFish--;
            return fff;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Pond with "+  numFish +" "+ fish[numFish];
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Fisher.likes(Fisher.java:34)
    at Fisher.goFishingIn(Fisher.java:53)
    at FishingTestProgram2.main(FishingTestProgram2.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Could anyone tell me why `p.catchAFish()` is not the same type in `likes(Fish f1)`?
because I think `catchAFish` method will return a Fish object which is same as the input type in `likes` method.

```
public class Fish {
    private String species;
    private int size;
    public String getSpecies(){
        return species;
    }
    public int getSize(){
        return size;
    }
    public Fish(int s, String ss){
        size=s;
        species=ss;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "A " + size+"cm "+ species;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class FishingTestProgram2 { 
    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        // Create a big pond with 15 fish 
        Pond bigPond = new Pond(15); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(4, "Sunfish")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(25, "Pike")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(20, "Bass")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(30, "Perch")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(14, "Sunfish")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(15, "Pike")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(9, "Pike")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(12, "Bass")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(5, "Sunfish")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(12, "Sunfish")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(10, "Bass")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(2, "Bass")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(16, "Perch")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(30, "Sunfish")); 
        bigPond.add(new Fish(7, "Perch")); 
        bigPond.listFish(); 

        // Create two people to fish in the pond 
        Fisher fred = new Fisher("Fred", 15); 
        Fisher suzy = new Fisher("Suzy", 10); 

        System.out.println("First Fred catches 20 fish in the big pond ..."); 
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
            fred.goFishingIn(bigPond); 
        fred.listFish(); 

        System.out.println("Suzy now catches 20 fish in the big pond ..."); 
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) 
            suzy.goFishingIn(bigPond); 
        suzy.listFish(); 

        System.out.println("Here is what is left of the pond ..."); 
        bigPond.listFish();
        // Now simulate Suzy giving her fish to Fred 
        suzy.giveAwayFish(fred, bigPond); 
        fred.listFish(); 
        suzy.listFish(); 
        bigPond.listFish();  
    } 
}
```

The string compare line was right I change it whileI was trying to solve the problem.
 The debugging says this. means Fish and p. means (int, string) I need to initialize these two thing in same type, but I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Whole lot of ... fishing ... going on today.

Comment: Did you mean: `int num= (int)(Math.random() % (numFish-1));` ?

Comment: the code is long  but the problem is just in two methods : goFishingIn method and likes method. wait for yours reply thank you

Comment: is there any difference with % and *?

Comment: Any difference between `%` and `*`? Perhaps you should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: `%` is modulo, `*` is multiplication. They are very different, yes.

Comment: P.S. which is line `34` of `Fisher` (`Fisher.java:34`)?

Comment: Why you are not debugging. You will find the problem in 5 minute.

Comment: Could you post the `Fish.java` and your `main` code ?

Comment: i debug it but i cant understand whats wrong with it

Comment: `if(f1.getSpecies()=="Sunfish")` This is going to cause other problems. Please read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: this is the first time i post the question please wait i will post the rest program as well.

Answer (score 2):

`catchAFish()` is returning null and so your `likes()` is getting a null reference in likes when you call `if(f1.getSpecies()=="Sunfish")` because you are passing in `if(likes(p.catchAFish())){ // the problem happens here`.

I don't see how `goFishingIn()` is is called, you don't supply that code. But you are most likely calling it with an sad empty pond.

You either need to check for null before using the return value of catchAFish, or ensure that catchAFish will never return null. Right now it will.

Okay - I see your main function.  The problem is you are out fishing your pond.

```
  public Fish catchAFish(){

    int num= (int)(Math.random() * (numFish-1));
    if(fish[num]!=null && numFish>0){
      fff= fish[num];
      fish[num]= fish[numFish-1];
      fish[numFish-1]=null;
      numFish--;
      return fff;
    }
    else
      return null;
  }
```

You initalize your array to 20, but each time you fish you are removing a whole Fish class, so when you call `goFishingIn` you are removing one Fish object from your fish array in pond.

I think you want to remove a single fish, and once that fish species is all fished out fish[num] == 0, then remove the fish.

```
  public Fish catchAFish(){

    int num= (int)(Math.random() * (numFish-1));
    if(fish[num]!=null && numFish>0){
      fff= fish[num];
      fish[num]--;
      if (fish[num] == 0)
      { 
          // No more of this fish type, remove it from the pond.
          fish[num]= fish[numFish-1];
          fish[numFish-1]=null;
          numFish--;
      }
      return fff;
    }
    else
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: This will fix this problem, but like I said, but it doesn't solve the problem of what happens if your pond is really and truly out of fish. You should be checking for null (or better yet, create an `IsEmpty()` method on Pond) and check that before you try and fish first.  Also look into a `List` to simplify removing a fish - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html.

Comment: yeach i will firstly fix the pond class